# Why mvn command not download hibernate-distribution.jar file?

Tags: hibernate, maven-2, jar, m2eclipse

I am trying to add a hibernate-distribution.jar version 3.5.4-Final inside the dependencies of a pom.xml file. When I am issuing this command, `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0`, I get the following output. And when I check in my `.m2/repository` folder, I don't see hibernate-distribution.jar is download. May I know how could I download the jar file using mvn command?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Web3 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (default-cli) @ Web3 >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (default-cli) @ Web3 <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (default-cli) @ Web3 ---
[INFO] Adding support for WTP version 2.0.
[INFO] Using Eclipse Workspace: C:\Documents and Settings\kok.hoe.loh\workspace
[WARNING] Workspace defines a VM that does not contain a valid jre/lib/rt.jar: C
:\Program Files\Java\jre6
[INFO] no substring wtp server match.
[INFO] Using as WTP server : JBoss v4.2
[INFO] Adding default classpath container: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAIN
ER
[INFO] Unable to read jar manifest from C:\Documents and Settings\kok.hoe.loh\.m
2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-distribution\3.5.4-Final\hibernate-distribu
tion-3.5.4-Final.pom
[INFO] File C:\Documents and Settings\kok.hoe.loh\workspace\Web3\.project alread
y exists.
       Additional settings will be preserved, run mvn eclipse:clean if you want
old settings to be removed.
[INFO] Wrote Eclipse project for "Web3" to C:\Documents and Settings\kok.hoe.loh
\workspace\Web3.
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.418s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Sep 29 11:11:01 SGT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command doesn't download libraries, it just creates the configuration files to import your project into eclipse. Try `mvn compile` to compile your project, it will automatically download your libraries

Comment: If you are using m2e than don't use mvn maven-eclipse-plugin anymore.

Comment: may be help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074040/maven-failing-to-download-jar-dependencies][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074040/maven-failing-to-download-jar-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the following directory:

```
 C:\Documents and Settings\kok.hoe.loh\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\
```

Then run the following command again:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

this will download files that you newly added to POM

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was trying to import via *dependencies* instead of using *dependencyManagement* tag in pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you wrap your  section with  tags.