# Is the cacerts file missing in ubuntu 15.10 and openjdk-8-jdk?

Tags: ubuntu, java-8, java, jsse, ubuntu-15.10

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 and their openjdk-8-jdk (by apt-get).

Now I am missing the cacerts file.

There is a link at the usual location:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Oct 22 01:47 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -> /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

but nothing at /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts:

```
stat /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
stat: cannot stat ‘/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is due to a bug already reported here:
[Ubuntu bug ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1396760)

The ticket above links another similar [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/983302), which provides a workaround:

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates-java
$ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an error here that Gergely answer solved, if you trying to call external apis with ssl and got this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1903)
```

This solved

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates-java
$ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java
```

Answer (score 0):

In centos you gotta do this:

```
$ sudo dnf install ca-certificates
```