# Fresh clojure installation in Ubuntu - Error building classpath

Tags: java, maven, clojure

I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu on VirtualBox to try out Clojure. I followed the instructions @ https://clojure.org/guides/getting_started, installed all the deps, etc. but when I try to run the repl with `clj` I keep getting the following errors:

```
Error building classpath. Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.9.0
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.9.0
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:276)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:253)
    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha.extensions.maven$eval685$fn__687.invoke(maven.clj:79)
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:243)
    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha$expand_deps.invokeStatic(alpha.clj:170)
    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha$expand_deps.invoke(alpha.clj:152)
    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha$resolve_deps.invokeStatic(alpha.clj:215)
    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha$resolve_deps.invoke(alpha.clj:197)
    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha.script.make_classpath$create_classpath.invokeStatic(make_classpath.clj:59)
    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha.script.make_classpath$create_classpath.invoke(make_classpath.clj:52)
    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha.script.make_classpath$run.invokeStatic(make_classpath.clj:70)
    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha.script.make_classpath$run.invoke(make_classpath.clj:64)
    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha.script.make_classpath$_main.invokeStatic(make_classpath.clj:109)
    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha.script.make_classpath$_main.doInvoke(make_classpath.clj:84)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:702)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:657)
    at clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:317)
    at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:313)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:424)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:387)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:702)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.clojure:clojure:pom:1.9.0 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:261)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.clojure:clojure:pom:1.9.0 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:399)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1921)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:557)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:360)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:91)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:171)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:184)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:89)
    ... 61 more
```

Comment: I prefer running using `lein`. Try this page:  https://leiningen.org/

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I tried setting it up on Windows before, gave up, now tried Linux and still having trouble. Seems like getting Clojure to work is far from straightforward, that doesn't help much with adoption.

Comment: Running `lein repl` runs into the same errors as above. I have OpenJDK 8 installed

Comment: Could be this Ubuntu bug? https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/-ovhQXtzhgw/XBm_rfcICgAJ

Comment: Yes, looks like it. I will post the solution below

Comment: Did you get the same error on windows?  What about trying Ubuntu 16.04?  Can you run `java -version` from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a java certificate bug in Ubuntu, solution in the following SO post:

[Is the cacerts file missing in ubuntu 15.10 and openjdk-8-jdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439905/is-the-cacerts-file-missing-in-ubuntu-15-10-and-openjdk-8-jdk)