# Heroku stuck downloading dependencies

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I can't deploy application to heroku, this morning I successfuly deployed one, however for the past couple of hours I have no luck in doing so. Every time I try I'm stuck at this

```
remote:        [INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.0.9/maven-profile-2.0.9.jar (35 KB at 486.3 KB/sec)
```

I tried redeploying the app i deployed in the morning without any changes, same thing, created new heroku account and the same things happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Heroku. This is a problem with your internet connection or Apache's Maven repo (which is pretty stable).

I would recommend you attempt to deploy your application again on a computer with a better internet connection or just try again later!

This question here lists some more tips for attempting to fix this problem: [Maven failing to download jar dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074040/maven-failing-to-download-jar-dependencies)